# Javascript counter up with various setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, counter, settimeout

I created from various sources the simplest js counter up I could find. How can I make **different setTimeout** for each counter so both of them end at the same time?

UPDATE: I have minimized the right answer below and this is the final code:

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const duration = 2000; // Finish in 2 seconds
const speed    = 2000;
const state    = {};

const max = Math.max(...[...counters]
  .map(counter => +counter.dataset.target));
const tick = duration / max;

const updateCount = (counter) => {
  const target = +counter.dataset.target;
  const value  = +counter.dataset.value;
  const ratio  = target / max;
  const ms     = Math.ceil(ratio * tick);
  const incr   = target / speed;
  const newVal = value + incr;
 
  if (value < target) {
    counter.innerText = Math.floor(newVal);
    counter.dataset.value = newVal;
    setTimeout(updateCount, ms, counter);
  } else {
    counter.innerText = target;
    counter.dataset.value = target;
  }
};
counters.forEach(updateCount);
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-key="1" data-value="0" data-target="1000">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-key="2" data-value="0" data-target="2000">0</div>
```

Comment: You can't have both timers end at exactly the same time since JavaScript runs synchronously.

Comment: If they have different rates in milliseconds, then they would never end at the same time.

Comment: What if I use ids for every div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each timer has to run at an increases rate relative to the max time.

This is a rudimentary example, and it still may need some work. I also recmomment using the `dataset` property to store the value and only re-render the value (in case the result is a floating-point number).

```js
const results  = document.querySelector('.results');
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const duration = 2000; // Finish in 2 seconds
const speed    = 1000;
const state    = {};

const max = Math.max(...[...counters]
  .map(counter => +counter.dataset.target));
const tick = duration / max;

const updateCount = (counter) => {
  const target = +counter.dataset.target;
  const value  = +counter.dataset.value;
  const ratio  = target / max;
  const ms     = Math.ceil(ratio * tick);
  const incr   = target / speed;
  const newVal = value + incr;
  
  const { dataset: { key }} = counter;
  state[key] = {
    ...state[key],
    ratio, ms, incr, value
  };
  results.textContent = JSON.stringify(state, null, 2);
  
  if (value < target) {
    counter.innerText = Math.floor(newVal);
    counter.dataset.value = newVal;
    setTimeout(updateCount, ms, counter);
  } else {
    counter.innerText = target;
    counter.dataset.value = target;
  }
};

counters.forEach(updateCount);
```

```css
.results {
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-key="1" data-value="0" data-target="1000">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-key="2" data-value="0" data-target="2000">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-key="3" data-value="0" data-target="4000">0</div>

<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: It looks nice. I don't know js very well, but I will try to play with it and get back to you.

Comment: I made the proper adjustments and made the code much smaller. I will flag it as the right answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It works like this because your `setTimeout(updateCount, 100);` runs after 100 miliseconds. So when you are counting from 0 to 150 and you are adding a number once per 100ms it will be twice faster as counting to 300.

You can make it end at the same time, when you change `setTimeout()` to run after 50 miliseconds for counting to 300

Something like this
`setTimeout(updateCount150, 100);`
`setTimeout(updateCount300, 50);`

Of course you need to adjust those both functions accordingly.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to duplicate the js for every counter?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the avg, like this:

```js
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const speed = 1;
let avg=0;
counters.forEach(counter => {
   avg+=parseInt(counter.getAttribute('data-target'))
});
avg=avg/counters.length;
counters.forEach(counter => {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const count = +counter.innerText;
    const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target')
    const inc = counter.getAttribute('data-target') / (speed * avg);

    if (count < target) {

      counter.innerText = count + inc;

      setTimeout(updateCount, 100);
    } else {
      counter.innerText = target;
    }
  };

updateCount();
});
```

```html
<div class="counter" data-target="150">0</div>
                
<div class="counter" data-target="300">0</div>
```

Comment: It works nice but how can you hide the decimals?